# Android textviews and buttons clickable in ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I made listview populated by another xml layouts which is populated with json http array. 
In the listview i have 3 textviews which i want to be clickable, but when i add in onCreate a onClick method app force closes. What should i do, can someone give me an example?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/meni"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:dividerHeight="15.0sp"
   />
```

And in list_row_layout:

```
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/acceptTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pressed"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Accept"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textColor="#0D98BA"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
```

the Activity class

```
   @Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
      feedListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
      String url = "....";
      new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url);

      progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);



       accept = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acceptTV);


       accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {


               }
           });




}
```

LogCat

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MainActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and much more

Solution to problem by user3057145 
If you used adapter you can call textview inside adapter class only. You cant call textview in main activity.

And you can do onclick event in adapter class only.

holder.accept = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.acceptTV);

```
           holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                      holder.accept.setText("dafsafag");
                   }
               });
```

Comment: can you post your error code?

Comment: Did you have Create Your adapter?

Comment: I only have CustomListAdapter class which populates the listview with http json

Comment: post your code that we help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used adapter you can call textview inside adapter class only. You cant call textview in main activity.

And you can do onclick event in adapter class only.

Comment: Thank you. Works now how it should be :)

Answer (score 1):

It seams that ComponentInfo error. this error will show at some id was not present in XML but you are trying to use in java file. can you check that all element name are called perfectly.. try to debug step by step....

If every thing was perfect try to give the list view id as list and try.............